# How do I make a db connection to Excel that more than one user can open at same time?

Tags: vba, adodb

You've help me to get to this point and now I'm stuck again. The macro works fine, but only one person can run it at any given time. If two users try to run it at the same time, they get a Runtime error. When I click Debug, it takes me to "myConn.Open"

To clarify, I'm not trying to allow multiple users to edit the Excel spreadsheet. They are only opening it read-only to get values from it, not to add or edit it in any way.

```
Public Sub Letter()

Dim rngStory As Word.Range
Dim rngCount As Long
Dim mySQLquery As String
Dim myKey As String
Dim mySource As String
Dim slkAddresseeName, slkRegarding, slkFileNum, slkSalutation As String
Dim slkTemplate As String
Dim myConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim myRs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim slkTempDoc As String
    
' Prompt user for Login ID
myKey = InputBox("Enter Attorney or Paralegal LOGIN ID (e.g., jtorres or b324):")

' Make DB connection
    mySQLquery = "SELECT * FROM [All_Users$] WHERE LoginID = '" & myKey & "'"
    
    mySource = "\\servername\vol1\macros\master\LetterMemoDB.xlsx"
    Set myConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set myRs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    With myConn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & mySource & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"
    End With
    myConn.Open
    myRs.Open mySQLquery, myConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
' End of DB connections
```

My guess is I'm using ACE as the provider and maybe it can't support multiple, simultaneous connections.  What's the fix?

Comment: The error is: Rin-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':  The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file". It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.

Comment: FYI: The newer ACE.OLEDB.12.0 (that replaces JET.OLEDB.4.0) should use Excel **12.0**.

Comment: You could try adding `Mode=Read` to the connection string, and/or flagging the source file as Read Only.

Answer (score 0):

Fix was to change the Excel file to read-only via right click | Properties. Sorry for the stupid question.